# Can I call an extension method from inside a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

Is there a way to call an extension from within a generic class, where the variable class is also the extended class? Here is a sample piece of code. It does not compile.

```
public class GenericFoo<TFrom,TTo>
{
   public TTo GenericFoo(TFrom A)
   {
      return A.Bar();
   }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static MyType Bar(this MyExtendedType source)
    {
       return new MyType();
    }
}
```

This produces the following error:

> 'TFrom' does not contain a definition for 'Bar' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   'MyNamespace.Extensions.Bar(MyNamespace.MyExtendedType)' has some
>   invalid arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if you add a *generic type constraint*:

```
public class GenericFoo<TFrom, TTo>
    where TFrom : MyExtendedType
    where TTo : MyType
{
   public TTo SomeMethod(TFrom A)
   {
      return (TTo)A.Bar();
   }
}
```

This will be enough to get it to compile, though you will still get a run-time error if no cast exists from `MyType` to `TTo`.

**Further Reading**

- [where (generic type constraint) (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

Comment: Ok, that kind of defeats the purpose of the generic class in the first place. But it seems like it is accurate.

Comment: @ArturoHernandez How do you expect to be able to call `Bar` without knowing that it's parameter is actually a `MyExtendedType`? Generics allow you to create patterns of behaviors with one or more types, without knowing exactly what those types will be at compile-time, but you still have to know what you can do with those types to be able to establish the pattern.

Comment: @ArturoHernandez I'd recommend defining an interface, `ISource`, and defining `Bar` as `Bar(ISource source)`, then using the constraint `where TFrom : ISource`. That way your generic class will be compatible with a much wider variety of type parameters.

Comment: @pswg I can see my problem here. I was hoping there would be some sort of workaround, but I'm more pessimistic now. Because of my particular use case interfaces won't help, I appreciate the comment.

Comment: @ArturoHernandez You could always use a [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). Although using `dynamic` when a working generic solution exists feels somewhat… icky.